# date_default_timezone_set works on one server but not the other

Tags: php

I still need to get specs from the server it does NOT work on, but:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
```

On my Mac OS X server with php 5.4.17 it works as expected

On the other server it does NOT report the correct time.

Is there something on the other server where it would NOT have the right time database?

For example: `date("H i:s m/d");` does not report correct time.

How do I get more timezones installed?

Comment: What does `date('e')` return?

Comment: And while you're at it, do `var_dump(date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam'));` to see if it actually worked.

Comment: `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()` returns a list of available timezones. If that does not contain Europe/Amsterdam, it's not a valid timezone for the server.

Comment: How would I get more timezones installed?

Comment: That depends on the server (OS, etc). The easiest solution would be to tell the server admin to install more timezones.

Comment: Would this be the correct place to point the sys admin?

http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb

Comment: @ChrisMuench that would install it only in PHP, but it might be a good idea to install it system-wide to have the time zones available in other applications (like DB server, etc).